# C# converting only one channel of YCbCr to RGB

Tags: c#, image-processing

This is what I use to convert one YCbCr value to one RGB pixel.

```
r = Math.Max(0.0f, Math.Min(1.0f, (float)(ycbcr.Y + 0.0000 * ycbcr.Cb + 1.4022 * ycbcr.Cr)));
g = Math.Max(0.0f, Math.Min(1.0f, (float)(ycbcr.Y - 0.3456 * ycbcr.Cb - 0.7145 * ycbcr.Cr)));
b = Math.Max(0.0f, Math.Min(1.0f, (float)(ycbcr.Y + 1.7710 * ycbcr.Cb + 0.0000 * ycbcr.Cr)));

return new Rgb((byte)(r * 255), (byte)(g * 255), (byte)(b * 255));
```

I get this when I try to simply return g and b as 0 and r as the `ycbcr.Cr` value.

[image]

Is this correct?

Edit: on the right you are seeing the effects of this.

```
r = Math.Max(0.0f, Math.Min(1.0f, (float)(ycbcr.Cr)));
g = 0.0f;
b = 0.0f;

return new Rgb((byte)(r * 255), (byte)(g * 255), (byte)(b * 255));
```

Comment: Not really sure how you expect us to tell if what you coded is what you wanted?

Comment: Mostly wanted to know if the right side looks like the Cr channel.
I used a common image for that reason.

Comment: Yes it looks like Cr channel (It has less content as mostly would go into Y and it is behaving like basic Cr chroma). If it suffice you then it is. For more details, pls explain your question.

Comment: Right now this is me playing around with basic image manipulation. In the end the program should be able to emulate mpeg compression.
One of the things I need to be able to do is sub-sample correctly and right now I am not 100% on whether I am splitting my program into YCbCr correctly.
I guess I was hoping somebody would be able to tell me if what I was doing at least looked right.